# Isomorphism from module $A\times B\otimes_{A\times B} M$ to product module $A\otimes_A M\times B\otimes_B M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Given two rings, $A$, $B$, and a module $(A\times B)\otimes M$, is there an isomorphism 
$$\big(A\otimes_A M\big)\times \big(B\otimes_B M\big) \overset{h}{\longrightarrow} \big(A\times B\big) \otimes_{A\times B} M$$

I've tried some of the (seemingly) obvious choices, but none of them seem to work out. If there is one, a push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Over what base should the tensor products be formed?

Comment: Sorry, updated the notation.

Comment: Okay, so $M$ is simultaneously an $A$-module, a $B$-module, and an $A\times B$ module, and as an $A\times B$ module, $M$ is isomorphic to $M_A \times M_B$ where $M_R$ is $M$ as an $R$-module?

Comment: Try using the universal property from the $(A\times B) \times M$ to the direct product, defined by the product of the protections on the first part.

Comment: No matter what, $R\otimes_R M \cong M$, so there is little chance in there being an isomorphism such as the one you suggest, even if it made sense for $M$ to be an $A\times B$ module, an $A$-module and a $B$-module